# Powershell Get-ChildItem returns nothing for folder

Tags: powershell, directory, path, get-childitem, shared-directory

A friend of mine asked me to write a short script for him. The script should check a specific folder, find all files and subfolders older than X days and remove them. Simple so far, I wrote the script, successfully tested it on my own system and sent it to him. Here's the thing - it doesn't work on his system. To be more specific, the Get-ChildItem cmdlet does not return anything for the provided path, but it gets weirder even, more on that later. I'm using the following code to first find the files and folders (and log them before deleting them later on):

```
$Folder = "D:\Data\Drive_B$\General\ExchangeFolder"

$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$TimeSpan = "-1"
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($TimeSpan)    

$FilesInFolder = (Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete})
```

All variables are filled and we both know that the folder is filled to the brim with files and subfolders older than one day, which was our timespan we chose for the test. Now, the interesting part is that not only does Get-ChildItem not return anything - going to the folder itself and typing in "dir" does not return anything either. Never seen behaviour like this. I've checked everything I could think of - is it DFS?, typos, folder permissions, share permissions, hidden files, ExecutionPolicy. Everything is as it should be to allow this script to work properly as it did on my own system when initially testing it. The script does not return any errors whatsoever.

So for some reason, the content of the folder cannot be found by powershell. Does anyone know of a reason why this could be happening? I'm at a loss here :-/

Thanks for your time & help,

Fred

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` does not do you any favors with error detection. You should try `-ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: Well `dir` and `Get-ChildItem` are literally the same thing in Powershell. Run `Get-Alias dir` to see what I mean. Try going into `cmd.exe` and running `dir` for the directory.

Comment: As there is a dollar sign in your path (which is used for variables), you should use a single quotes to prevent PowerShell from interpreting it: `$Folder = 'D:\Data\Drive_B$\General\ExchangeFolder'`

Comment: As aside: [DateTime.AddDays()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays) takes a [double] as parameter, not a string, so take off the quotes here: `$TimeSpan = -1`

Comment: As per @iRon's comment, which is indeed the issue, you can alternatively escape the `$` with ``"D:\Data\Drive_B`$\General\ExchangeFolder"``

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers :-D I'll change the script accordingly and retry. Might take a while though, but I'll get back and share the results as soon as I have them.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing a similar issue and can't figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

> .AddDays() takes an double I would use that.

> Filter then action

> This code will work for you.

```
$folder = Read-Host -Prompt 'File path'

$datetodel = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$results = try{ gci -path $folder -Recurse  | select FullName, LastWriteTime | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt $datetodel}}catch{ $Error[-1] }
$info = "{0} files older than: {1} deleting ...." -f $results.count, $datetodel

if($results | ogv -PassThru){
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($info)
    #Put you code here for the removal of the files
    # $results | % del FullName -force
}else{
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Exiting")
}
```